# Cordova Sqlite Thread safe issue

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I am using the Cordova sqlite plugin in my Phonegap project to save the data locally. In that I am using the db transactions multiple times to communicate with the SQlite DB. When I run the project on iOS m getting below error and the app will display blank screen. Sometimes it will work properly.

> `[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 163] Good news: SQLite is thread safe!`

. 
How can I run the db transactions in seperate thread thread. Please help..Thanks in advance.